# Pyspark dataframe write to single json file with specific name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which I want to write it as single json file with a specific name. I tried below

```
df2 = df1.select(df1.col1,df1.col2)
df2.write.format('json').save('/path/file_name.json') # didnt work, writing in folder 'file_name.json' and files with part-XXX
df2.toJSON().saveAsTextFile('/path/file_name.json')  # didnt work, writing in folder 'file_name.json' and files with part-XXX
```

but it didn't work. How to do it?

Answer (score 31):

You need to save this on single file using below code:-

```
df2 = df1.select(df1.col1,df1.col2)
df2.coalesce(1).write.format('json').save('/path/file_name.json')
```

This will make a folder with `file_name.json`. Check this folder you can get a single file with whole data `part-000`

Comment: I wanted to write with a specific name file_name.json. Is there a direct way of writing it, other than renaming it ?

Comment: instead writing this file_name.json use your name like file_name

Comment: Because you are using spark, your data is spread across multiple nodes, computing in parallel and sent in part to your directory. One of the reasons to use spark is that the data cannot be stored locally. So this is how the data is output. The larger your file the larger more "part" files should come through.

Comment: @LijjuMathew: This should be what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60442604/530399

Answer (score 9):

You can do it by converting to a pandas df previously:

```
df.toPandas().to_json('path/file_name.json', orient='records', force_ascii=False, lines=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

Pyspark stores the files in smaller chunks and as far as I know, we can not store the JSON directly with a single given file name. I think this small python function will be helpful to what you're trying to achieve.

```
def saveResult (data_frame, temp_location, file_path):
    data_frame.write.mode('append').json(temp_location)
    file = dbutils.fs.ls(temp_location)[-1].path # last file is the json or can also use regex to determine this
    dbutils.fs.cp(file, file_path)
    dbutils.fs.rm(temp_location, recurse=True)
```

Basically, what's happening here is you are passing the data frame, the temp_location where all the file chunks are stored and the full file path (file path + filename) which you'd like to get as an output file. The function generates the chunks, deletes all the chunks, and saves the final file into the desired location with the desired file name.

Comment: dbutils is DataBricks ONLY.

Comment: Using Fabric, mssparkutils achieves the same result

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
# Import necessary libraries
import os
import glob

# Write the DataFrame as JSON (default will be a folder with multiple files)
df.write.json('data_output')

# Retrieve the part file matching the pattern 'part-0000*' within 'data_output' directory
files = glob.glob('data_output/part-0000*')

if files:
    # Rename the part file to data.json in current dir
    os.rename(files[0], '/path/file_name.json')
    
    # Remove data_output dir
    os.system("rm -rf data_output")
```

If you have a large df that creates multiple "part" files you'll need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like :

```
transformed_noti_overdue_trainee_df.coalesce(1).write.json(path/stage", mode="overwrite")
files = mssparkutils.fs.ls(path/stage")
for filename in files:   #This function will return the part filename created by Spark writer above-->Spark creates partition file like part1......json
    if filename.name.endswith('.json'):
        name=filename.name
# Copying the stage file to actual output folder with custom name -->This is done only to rename the file as required.
dbutils.fs.cp(path/stage/"+name, path/Output/Name.json",True)
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's another approach:

```
import os
df2 = df1.select(df1.col1,df1.col2)
df2.write.format('json').save('/path/folder_name')

os.system("cat /path/folder_name/*.json > /path/df.json")
os.system("rm -rf /path/folder_name")
```

Assuming this is done in the analysis phase and the exporting as a single json doesn't get carried into prod.