# How to store an Array[String] to an output file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm having an Array[String] called samparr with some values in it, I want it to get stored as an output file.

```
var samparr: Array[String] = new Array[String](4)
samparr +:= print1 + "  BEST_MATCH  " + print2
```

just like,

```
val output = samparr.saveAsTextFile(outputpath)
```

but isn't a RDD its an Array[String]

Comment: the community get mad, the marked question as duplicate is not for the same purpose as this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `SparkContext.parallelize` to "distribute" your Array onto the Spark cluster (in other words, to turn it into an RDD), and then call `saveAsTextFile`:

```
sc.parallelize(samparr).saveAsTextFile(outputpath)
```

This action will partition the data and send each partition to one of the executors, then each partition will be saved into a separate "file-part".

**Alternatively**, since the array is very small and doesn't really "justify" using Spark, you can try any non-Spark method of saving data to file, e.g. the one linked by [@avihoo-mamka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455626/avihoo-mamka): [How to write to a file in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604237/how-to-write-to-a-file-in-scala)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I expected. Tzach Zohar you Rock.!