Not able to create CSV using Spark dataframe and scala, Instead it is creating folder with `.csv` in folder name
I am not able to write or create csv using spark dataframe. Instead it is creating directoy for me. This is my code
package com.package.dssupplier

import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, concat_ws}

import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

object DataSupplier extends Serializable {
  private val s3_input_loc: String = sys.env.getOrElse("S3_INPUT_PATH", "s3a://bucketname/data/export-db/dev/")

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("DataSupplier Main started....................")
    val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder().appName("DataSupplier")
      .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.marksuccessfuljobs", "false")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain")
      .config("spark.sql.files.overwrite", "true")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
    sqlContext.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN");

    val latestDF = sqlContext.read.text(s3_input_loc + "latest.txt").toDF("timestamp").select("timestamp")
    val latest = latestDF.first().getString(0)
    val dataPath = s3_input_loc + "/" + latest + "/dta/1/"

    sqlContext.read.parquet(dataPath).createOrReplaceTempView("dataTable")

    val dataQuery = "SELECT primaryid FROM dataTable WHERE name = 'John' limit 10"
    val dataResults = sqlContext.sql(dataQuery);
    dataResults.createOrReplaceTempView("dataResults")
    dataResults.show(100)

    val timestamp = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))
    val outputFileName = s"file_${timestamp}.csv"

    dataResults
      .withColumn("primaryid", concat_ws("$", col("primaryid")))
      .write.option("delimiter", "\t").option("header", "true")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
      .save(path =  "C:\\Users\\name\\output.csv")

    sqlContext.stop()
  }
}

but instead of creating csv file, it is creating folder output.csv/_temporary\0 and there is no csv file. Please let me know how to fix, Thanks

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661660/spark-how-to-write-a-single-csv-file-without-folder

Spark DataFrameWriter.csv method writes the output in a directory and not as a file, please refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv.html#pyspark-sql-dataframewriter-csv

Spark save function takes path to save the file & you can't control file name.

Does this answer your question? Spark - How to write a single csv file WITHOUT folder?

As spark writes in a folder it is neccessary first to repartition to 1 as then only 1 partition is written in this subfolder. Afterwards some system os operations are necessary to move it from the subfolder to the parent folder content. Unfortunately I have only the code in python/pyspark but it gives you the idea on how to do it:

import os
import shutil
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Union


def save_as_one_csv_file(
    data: DataFrame,
    output_file: str,
    null_value: str = "null",
    sep: str = ",",
    empty_value: str = "§§",
):
    """
    Saves a spark dataframe as a single csv file.

    * Fills up null values with the String "null", as applications like QlikSense
    cannot differentiate between empty strings and
    null values in csv data.
    * Uses separator ",", and "§" for quoting and empty
    strings as this is a rarely used
    character and qlik has problems reading quoted data.
    * Ensures that the final output is a csv file in the given
    output path, not a folder as used by spark.

    :param data: The spark dataframe to write.
    :param output_file: The output path for writing the csv file.
    :param null_value: Null values that needs to get replaces by character
    :param sep:
    :param empty_value:
    """

    localpath = get_local_path(output_file)
    (
        data.repartition(1)
        .write.mode("overwrite")
        .option("header", True)
        .option("sep", sep)
        .option("quote", "§")
        .option("emptyValue", empty_value)
        .option("nullValue", null_value)
        .option("escape", "§")
        .csv(output_file + "_temp")
    )
    file = [file for file in os.listdir(localpath + "_temp") if file.endswith(".csv")][
        0
    ]
    os.replace(os.path.join(localpath + "_temp", file), localpath)

    tmp_file_path = localpath + "_temp"
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_file_path)


In case you are on databricks it is necessary to transform your dbfs path to local paths to perform system os operations.
def get_local_path(path: Union[str, Path]) -> str:
    """
    Transforms a potential dbfs path to a
    path accessible by standard file system operations

    :param path: Path to transform to local path
    :return: The local path
    """
    return str(path).replace("dbfs:", "/dbfs")


