# Convert pyspark dataframe to json file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have a dataframe below and want to write that contents to a `.json` file.

[image: Sample input dataframe and expected output json]

And while creating output files , I do not want success part log files, so I tried to collect () the values from dataframe and used `json_dumps()` to create the file. But i am losing the column names and formats as opposed to the expected format in picture

Please help!

Comment: Please post the code you tried, not just a picture.

Comment: Does  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43269244/pyspark-dataframe-write-to-single-json-file-with-specific-name) answer your question?